# Update sObject attribute via Salesforce API

Tags: java, salesforce

I am working with data between an application and a related set of data in salesforce, in this case opportunities.  I want to update some attributes of the opportunity over api, how to I do this?  Lets say my attribute is called

```
My_Attribute__c
```

I understand that SOQL does not have an updates statement, so for some opportunity, how do I programmatically update its My_Attribute__c attribute?  Incidentally this is in Java.  Shoudl I just use the sObject PATCH service call?

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_update_fields.htm

Comment: It looks like you already have an answer.

Comment: yes, an answer, but so many http calls to update multiple properties of the same object?

Comment: Oh excuse me, yes, I can do all fields that way, I do have an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is here, a post with an http method name PATCH

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_update_fields.htm